# integrating Stripe.com and Parse.com with iOS - can't add a subscription to a customer

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, parse-platform, stripe-payments

Thanks in advance!

I've been smashing my head against my desk all day trying to figure out why I can't add a Stripe subscription to a customer via Parse.

Here is what my dictionary looks like in objective-C:

```
NSDictionary *productInfo = @{ @"tokenId": token.tokenId,
                               @"plan": @"Test Plan",
                               @"email": currentUser.email };
```

I'm calling this PFCloud function in the background:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("createSubscription", function(request, response) {

var Stripe = require('stripe');

// Test
Stripe.initialize('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');

Stripe.Customers.create({

    card: request.params.tokenId,
    email: request.params.email,
    plan: request.params.plan

},  {

    success: function(httpResponse) {
        response.success("Success - subscription created");
    },

    error: function(httpResponse) {
        response.error("Error - subscription canceled");
    }

})

});
```

I've interchanged "card" with "source" as mentioned in Stripe's documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/subscriptions.

I've also tried using the plan Id rather than name. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I forgot to mention that I am getting this error message, half of which I wrote - [Error]: Error - subscription canceled (Code: 141, Version: 1.6.3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that is interested in integrating Parse and Stripe, here is the solution. I talked to the good people at Stripe customer support and they told me two important things.

First, if you are using the newest Stripe API version (2015-02-18) then you're going to want to use the key "source" but if you are using an older version then you're going to want to use the key "card".

Second, make sure to use the ID of your plan rather than it's name for the key "plan".